# SilverStripe 3.1.x - DataList Unique Field value filter / How to use ORM to count items in Grouped List?

Tags: filter, field, silverstripe, datalist

In SilverStripe, one can fetch a bunch of records, like so:

```
$entryRecords = Entry::get()->sort('Email');
```

If I want to find out how many Entry records I have, I can call the count method on the DataList, like this:

```
$totalEntryRecords = $entryRecords->count();
```

If I want to find out how many unique Email addresses are in those records using the SilverStripe ORM in PHP from the DataList without writing a loop and without resorting to running new custom DB query, how would I do that?

Here’s what I've tried so far and it does not work:

```
GroupedList::create($entryRecords)->groupBy('Email')->Count(); // does not work
```

I get the following fatal error:
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function Count() on a non-object

The GroupedList API shows that there is a Count method.  So not sure why that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

ok this works...

```
count(GroupedList::create($entryRecords)->groupBy('Email'));
```

Answer (score 1):

why not just "select [distinct](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataList.html#_distinct) [email](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataList.html#_setQueriedColumns) from ..."?

e.g.

```
$uniqueEmailsCount =  Entry::get()->distinct()->setQueriedColumns(array('Email'))->count();
```

I guess this is more performant.

Comment: Didn't know about `setQueriedColumns`, that is useful! Yep, I would figure yours would be faster than manually enumerating the `GroupedList` as yours would run on the DB vs pulling back all the records and looping in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a method called "distinct" in DataList,

```
$counter = GroupedList::create(SomeDataObject::get())->GroupedBy('Title')->count();
```

Is your best option.

Comment: [There actually is as @wmk linked in his answer.](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataList.html#_distinct)

Comment: @wmk my bad, I searched for it in a 3.0 site. That function was introduced in 3.1